# Creating an object where the class name on the left and right sides are different

Tags: java, oop

I have seen a few references of instantiating a new object as follows, especially when using Inheritance.

```
Cat cat = new Animal();
```

However, I do not know what this concept is called. and so, I'm unable to read up on it.

I have two questions.

1. What is this concept called?
2. How is this possible, that, you can
       hold/refer to an object using a type that is different from it's
       original class?

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept in play here is **inheritance**.  A good place to start reading about it is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Your example is reversed — it should be

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
```

This is because the `Cat` class would be a specific kind of `Animal` — having everything needed to make an `Animal` object, plus some extras.

In code, this could look something like:

```
public class Test
{
    public static class Animal
    {
        protected String sound;
        public String getSound() { return sound; }
        public Animal() { sound = ""; }
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal
    {
        public Cat() { super(); sound = "meow"; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Cat();
        System.out.println(animal.getSound());
    }
}
```

And the result would be

> meow

because the Cat object has the `getSound()` method from the parent Animal, but was created with its own constructor and set the data appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

1. In object oriented programming world, this concept is called as inheritance.
2. It is possible to assign a child's object to parent's reference. Err, too techie, eh? So take it this way, a `Cat` is a kind of `Animal`, but the reverse is not necessarily true.
   So, an `Animal` can be a `Cat`, `Dog`, or whatever, because cats and dogs do have properties of an animal. This is also called generalization and specialization. An `Animal` is a generalized category, but a `Cat` is a specialized category of `Animal`s.

There are a lot of resources available on the Internet. Have a look and learn about the Object Oriented Programming paradigm. Good luck!